# Reversing a list but not reversing it at the same time

Tags: python

```
def fun1(input):    
    input.reverse()       
    return input
```

this works fine for `fun1([1,2,3])`

but when i want to do something like this

```
input = [p,q,r]
print fun1(input)
print input
```

for both the above statements output is `[r,q,p]` but I want it to remain `[p,q,r]`.

[image]

Comment: Do you want to reverse or not? What *exactly* is the expected output?

Comment: [`list.reverse` 'reverses the items of s in place'](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#mutable-sequence-types).

Comment: i want to reverse the input and i want get the reversed output and initial input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `input` as a name will shadow the builtin `input` function, so that's a bad idea.

To keep `input_` intact, you can modify a copy of it, instead of modifying it directly:

```
def fun1(input_):

      input_copy = input_[:] # A copy of input via slicing
      input_copy.reverse()
      return input_copy # return the mutated copy of your input
```

You can also use the explicit `copy` function to make a shallow copy:

```
input_copy = input_.copy()
```

Your `input_` will not be modified and changes on the copy will not propagate to the original `input_`

Answer (score 0):

Assign new local variable for the reversed list and return it:

```
def fun1(input):
    output = input[:]
return output.reverse()
```